# Curious behaviour of PHP arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I am writing a photo album app and ran in to a curious problem which only seems to be evident on my production server with PHP 5.5.6 and not on my development machine which has PHP 5.4.7. I'm wondering whether this issue is due to the new version of PHP (either not being aware of a feature or a bug), the configuration of the two servers being different or a combination of both.

I have the following function defined in class `Data`:

```
public static function getAlbum ($key)
{
    $stmt = self::$db->prepare ("SELECT * FROM `albums` WHERE `album_key` = ?;");
    $stmt->execute (array ($key));
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if (array_key_exists (0, $rows))
    {
        return $rows [0];
    }
    else
    {
        return array ();
    }
}
```

For a given `$key`, this function is tested and works.

In the calling code, I have the following:

```
$album = Data::getAlbum ($_REQUEST ['key']);
$page->bodyAppend ("&gt; {$album ['album_name']} ");
```

Performing a `print_r` of the `$album` variable shows that the index `'album_name'` *is* present in the array, thereby implying that the value `$_REQUEST ['key']` is a valid key and the method `Data::getAlbum` works as anticipated. However, this code generates a notice in the log: `PHP Notice:  Undefined index: album_name in <<filename>> on line <<line#>>`

Curiously, however, the string is correctly appended via the `bodyAppend` method, including the value from the (apparently) undefined index.

This notice message disappears if I modify the code to read:

```
$album = Data::getAlbum ($_REQUEST ['key']);
if (isset ($album ['album_name']))
{
    $page->bodyAppend ("&gt; {$album ['album_name']} ");
}
```

or if I modify the code as follows:

```
$album = Data::getAlbum ($_REQUEST ['key']);
if (count ($album) > 0)
{
    $page->bodyAppend ("&gt; {$album ['album_name']} ");
}
```

Any clues?

I don't dispute that advanced checking for the existence of a key is a good thing (so I'm happy to leave my modifications in the code) - but this is the first time I've come across this sort of error.

Comment: General tip: don't put spaces into your array references. `$arr []` should be `$arr[]` to prevent any syntax ambiguities.

Comment: Does `print_r` on `$album` contains `'album_name'`? You said it contains `'album_key'`.

Comment: @MarcB - I've done the spaces-before-brackets thing my entire life, so its unlikely I'll change any time soon. Can you give a demonstration where syntax ambiguities might arise?

Comment: @Pang - yes, sorry: will edit that now. It contains all the info needed given that the query is `SELECT *...`.

Comment: at least with the `{}` you're papering over the problem, but `echo "$arr [key]"` would output `Array [key]`, not the value of that array's key.

Comment: Try logging calls to `return array ();` in `else` part in `getAlbum()` and see if that line is executed?

Comment: @Pang - in my testing I had a giant `echo "BOO"; exit();` in that `else` (before the `return`...) and it is never executed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common pattern of error that I've learned to recognize:

- Function is doing what it is supposed to do
- Function is throwing an error that means it should be able to do what it is supposed to do

These have run me around in circles in the past, but they always boil down to the following:

- Somehow, I'm calling the function more times than I think I am

Go though your code and look at all of the places that you call the function. Print the arguments out right before you call it. Most likely, you'll find that you are calling the function more times then you thought you were, with arguments that aren't valid somehow.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried that first with a simple `echo` message inside the method itself, with the input parameters, being sent every time the method was called. There were no unexpected calls.

Comment: As suggested above, this might be an issue with your spaces before the indexing brackets []. Try getting rid of those.

Comment: The brackets have no effect. The comment is only relevant to parsing mid-string variables that are not surrounded by `{}`. In my testing, changed the output line to `$page->bodyAppend ("&gt; " . $album ['album_name'] . " ");` which produced the same notice.